# How are we to understand the words "womb" "begotten" and "morning" in Psalm 110:3?

Tags: word-study, psalms

Psalm 110:3 Brenton Septuagint Translation, With thee is dominion in the day of thy power, in the splendours of thy saints: ***I have begotten thee from the womb before the morning.***

Psalm 110:3 Peshitta Holy Bible Translated Version says, Your people are glorious in the day of power; ***in the glories of holiness from the womb, from the first, I have begotten you, Son***

Other translations, like the American Standard Version  have Psalm 110:3 as, Thy people offer themselves willingly In the day of thy power, in holy array: Out of the womb of the morning Thou hast the dew of thy youth

In this translation, what does "***Out of the womb of the morning Thou hast the dew of thy youth***" mean?

Comment: LXX differs from the Hebrew apparently, so you just need to refer the old topics discussing LXX vs Hebrew Masoretic and DSS transmission.

Comment: This is beautiful metaphoric poetry.

Comment: It would be more profitable to examine the Hebrew and discern a correct translation than merely pick one of many disparate translations and guess at what it means. (In my view.) It is clearly an imaginative, poetic statement and has presented translators with difficulty. Only expert analysis of the original Hebrew will arrive at a precise meaning.

Comment: @NigelJ. You can choose which translation you want and then answer the Q from that translation.

Comment: @AlexBalilo As I pointed out, in this case that would serve no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Psalm 110:3 (LEB)

```
 Your people ⌊will volunteer⌋ in the day of your power. 
 In holy splendor, from the womb of the dawn, 
 you will have the dew of your youth.
```

(The LEB translator note for "will volunteer" is *"Literally “will be freewill offerings”; see the related verbal form in Judg 5:2"*)

The OP, for some inexplicable reason, cites only translations of translations in the original question, which is why "childhood" - ילדות, yaldut (noun), from "yeled" or child - is mistranslated in those secondary translations as "begotten" (which is the hifil verb הוֹלִיד or *holid*). All English translations working directly from the Hebrew translate this as *childhood* or *youth*.

[image: interlinear]

Psalms are *poetry* and use *poetic language*, that is *metaphor* - there is not an actual "womb of the dawn" just as there is not an actual "dew of youth" :)

Rather, the *dew* of youth is the *doctrine or teaching* that comes from God *to the youth* (the ones instructed) like the dew that comes each day at daybreak.

Deuteronomy 32:2 (LEB)

```
 May my teaching trickle like the dew, 
 my words like rain showers on tender grass, 
 and like spring showers on new growth.
```

Notice that the dew falls on "tender" (young) grass and on "new" (young) growth. That is, the teaching is given to the young. And just as the dew, or rains, cause the plants to grow, so the teaching causes the youth to mature and grow in understanding and wisdom. But the tender grass needs more than dew, it also needs *light*, and thus our next metaphor:

The *womb* of dawn is the *source* of the dawn. Why is the word "womb" used in this poetic way? Other than considerations of sound and meter, "womb" - רחם is a pun on "mercy" which has the same consonants but with different pointing. It is God's *mercies that are renewed every dawn* [Lamentations 3.22]. The origin of the daybreak is God, as God is light, but it is also a reference to God's mercy in creating the light, this parallels the dew, which is God's mercy on the land. Both the dawn and dew are parallels in that they are metaphors for the gaining of understanding as well for that which is necessary for the plants to grow.

Luke 2:52 (KJV 1900)

> 52 And Jesus increased in wisdom and stature, and in favour with God
> and man.

Therefore this verse alludes to God's doctrine, or teaching, *being mercifully given to Messiah in his youth*, similar to the dew being given to the ground at dawn.